# Apache Camel Rest - How to send request and response from previous endpoint to next

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, apache-camel

I wanted to implement a camel DSL logic where e.g I have two routes where the request received for first route should be passed to second route along with the response from first route. How do I achieve this?

```
        `.to("direct:validatePayload")
            .to("bean:fundService?method=depositFund(${exchange})")
            .to("bean:rparticipantService?method=notifyParticipant(${exchange})");`
```

In the above code, after validating the request payload, the exchange which has the Fund body is passed as request to depositFund. After this, I wanted to pass the request to notifyParticipant which will be combination of response from depositFund along with the request that depositFund received. How do I achieve this through camel DSL code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Message History:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Message+History

In the `rparticipantService#notifyParticipant` you should be able to lookup history and get results of `fundService#depositFund`.

```java
List<MessageHistory> list = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.MESSAGE_HISTORY, List.class);
```

Also you will need to tune `MessageHistoryFactory` to be able to access the message + body:

```java
camelContext.getMessageHistoryFactory().setCopyMessage(true);
```